# Django models - is there a reasonable solution for handling sub dicts as a field in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm fairly new into Django and the Django orm. I need to model something like:

or in python psuedo code:

```
class Settings(Model):
    subsettings1 = somekindofdictfield({key:fields.BooleanField(), key:fields.BooleanField()})
    subsettings2 = somekindofdictfield({key:fields.BooleanField(), key:fields.BooleanField()})
```

I'm trying to avoide having to have seperate class for each kind of of subsettings. Which can be dynamic. So this solution look wrong:

```
class Settings(Model):
    subsettings1 = ForeignKey(SubSettings1)
    #etc
```

I'm not afraid of having many models (I already have) but I don't want unnecessary ones. with mode tables etc.. 
I'll be glad for ideas from exprienced Django developers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the settings are meant to be opaque (for example, you don't need to filter based on particular values in your dicts) you can just store these as regular Python objects using something like [django-picklefield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield).

```
>>> from picklefield.fields import PickledObjectField
... class SomeObject(models.Model): 
...     args = PickledObjectField()
>>> obj = SomeObject()
>>> obj.args = ['fancy', {'objects': 'inside'}]
>>> obj.save()
```

Comment: Nice to learn about picklefields. but I'm afraid I need to refer the values in the subsettings inside my models method etc..

Comment: @alonisser: Just to be clear, if you only need to *refer* to the settings in a given object, then the pickle field works just fine. You can just say `myobject.subsettings1['setting']`. If you need to perform database operations on those settings (using `filter`, for example) then there's no way around putting them in database fields, and creating tables to organize them. It might be possible to generalize your models using [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), but it's hard to say without knowing more detail.